# Breakpoints not Working in Xcode 3.2.5

Tags: iphone, breakpoints

I am using Xcode 3.2.5. I kept breakpoints in my code. But It is not working. Can any one tell how to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not conform to the expected format : stackoverflow.com/faq#questions . You should ask help to solve a real issue, not how to do something. Please, search by yourself and come back when you'll get stucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have much luck getting this question answered in a time where Xcode 4.4 just went GM and is ready to submit apps. Xcode 3 is *really* old and has it's fair share of problems. Time to move on.

To be fair, even in Xcode 4 breakpoints are not *always* working. But LLDB got a lot better and is pretty reliable now.

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes. steipete is right tho, the version you are using is very old, very few people still use it and are unable to provide valid first hand troubleshooting device.
Also you have not provided much info; has this just happened or always been the way? Was there an upgrade conflict? Project transfer?
More info means better help